# Check running lua scripts

Tags: cmd

There are several LUA scripts that must be constantly executed. For controlling its states, i wrote small cmd/batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextension enabledelayedexpansion
set LIST=C:\123\lua_list
set EXEC_CMD="lua.exe"

for /f %%a in (%LIST%) do (
wmic process where "name like '%EXEC_CMD%'" get commandline | findstr /i %%a > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo down
) else (
echo up
)
)
```

When executed, return "get was unexpected at this time"

Line with "wmic" run correctly in command prompt directly. Where is mistake?

I try with

- errorlevel == 1
- "name like 'lua.exe'" directly
- (name=%EXEC_CMD%)
- "name=%EXEC_CMD%"

lua_list contain full path to *.lua scripts, one by line.

Answer (score 1):

It's your double quoting in the command:

```
set EXEC_CMD="lua.exe"
```

This evaluates to :

```
wmic process where "name like '"lua.exe"'" get commandline
```

With too much double quotes.

Change the batch to
**EDIT new version using conditional execution**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\26\SO_53008258.cmd

@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "LIST=C:\123\lua_list"
set "EXEC_CMD=lua.exe"

for /f %%a in (%LIST%) do (
    wmic process where "name like '%EXEC_CMD%'" get commandline|findstr /i /c:"%%~a" >nul 2>&1 && (
        echo %%a up) || ( echo %%a down)
)
```

Successfully tested here with firefox.exe instead of lua.exe.
findstr is by default in reguar expression mode -> use /C: for exact matches.

Comment: As i say, i already try with "name like 'lua.exe'". Same error

Comment: @hAh0L13 see changes above.